# Objective C iPhone Playing Video with MediaPlayer dont work

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, media-player

On an app for iPhone,
I m trying to play a video with MediaPlayer but it wont work.
I use main Bundle to store video.
I have no error, but when i click to launch video, i have a blank screen.
My path seems correct. i dont understand why it wont work. thx for your help.
Here is my code:

```
#import "VideoViewController.h"

@interface VideoViewController ()

@end

@implementation VideoViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString *moviePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"myvideo" ofType:@"mp4"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: moviePath];
    NSLog(@"%@", url);

    self.moviePlayer =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:self.moviePlayer];

    self.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
    self.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:self.moviePlayer.view];
    [self.moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification {
    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [notification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     removeObserver:self
     name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
     object:player];

    if ([player
         respondsToSelector:@selector(setFullscreen:animated:)])
    {
        [player.view removeFromSuperview];
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: None can help for this please ? I m still trying to find a solution. I just have a blank screen, no video :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i found a solution ! Hope this will help others too ;)

```
#import "VideoViewController.h"

@interface VideoViewController ()

@end

@implementation VideoViewController
{
    BOOL didPlay;
}

- (void)playMovie
{
    didPlay = YES;

    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString *moviePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"myvideo" ofType:@"mp4"];
    NSURL *mediaURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath];

    // play
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:mediaURL];
    player.moviePlayer.allowsAirPlay = YES;
    player.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;

    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:player];

    id observer1;
    id observer2;

    observer1 = [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:player.moviePlayer queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] usingBlock:^(NSNotification *notification)
     {
         [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:observer1];
         [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:observer2];
     }];

    observer2 = [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification object:player.moviePlayer queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] usingBlock:^(NSNotification *notification)
     {
         if ((player.moviePlayer.loadState & MPMovieLoadStatePlayable) != 0)
             [player.moviePlayer performSelector:@selector(play) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0f];
     }];
}

- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    if (!didPlay) [self playMovie];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    didPlay = NO;

    self.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
    [self.view addSubview:self.moviePlayer.view];
}


- (IBAction)goBack:(id)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"back" sender: self];
    NSLog(@"ok");
}
@end
```